# array push returns double quotation instead of actual value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to push input value into the array but I get just "" double quotation as outcome. THE CODE:

```
function handletyping(event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        insertName(event.target.value);  
        console.log(globalNames);
    }
    inputName.addEventListener('keyup', handletyping); 
    inputName.focus();                     
}
```

Then I get:

array: [One, Two, Three, ""] --> instead of showing the value of what I type in the input, the array just shows double quotes. Please, help me!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It would appear that `event.target.value` is a blank string (most likely) or a pair of quotes (less likely) as of when `handletyping` is called. We can't help you understand why that is from what little is in the question. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).